# MS Project Task - Start and End Date Incorrect - 1 Day is going in to the next

Tags: task, ms-project

My start and end dates are not correct. eg a 1 day task is actually ending on day 2.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check that both in your application and if you are using customer calender the Working Week is set correctly for start/end times. You can find infomation on that here - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-the-general-working-days-and-times-for-a-project-c4587751-2b88-449d-87e5-d3312d16771d

2) Check that the resource/s have that calander assigned to them

3) If your start/end is been pushed in to the next day this is potentially due to the start of the task actually been some where with in the start date and not at the begining of the day. Check the task and if needs be Constrain to Start No Ealier Than. Alterntivly you may need to shorten prevous tasks.

Terran